# NSBundle pathForResource returns nil with subdirs

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, nsbundle

I have a bunch of directories and files in my app, for instance `images/misc/mainmenu_background.`. I'm running the following code in the "iPad Simulator 3.2":

```
NSString *images = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:nil];
NSString *images_misc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images/misc" ofType:nil];
NSString *images_misc_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images/misc/mainmenu_background.png" ofType:nil];
```

After this call, `images` contains the path `/Users/wic/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/8F67150B-71E6-4735-8CC6-38B3CE6D3568/Foo.app/images`.

**But `images_misc` and `images_misc_file` are `nil`**. Double-checking my file system to check if the file is there:

```
$ ls -l "/Users/wic/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/8F67150B-71E6-4735-8CC6-38B3CE6D3568/Foo.app/images/misc/mainmenu_background.png"
-rw-rw-rw-  1 wic  staff  30307 16 Feb 21:09 /Users/wic/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/8F67150B-71E6-4735-8CC6-38B3CE6D3568/Foo.app/images/misc/mainmenu_background.png
```

Apparently the file is there.

If I switch to "iPad Simulator 4.0", or any other simulator version for that matter everything works as expected.

Is there something wrong with my setup, or is this correct behavior for `NSBundle` in iPad 3.2? I have no actual physical iPad to test it on unfortunately.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to access a file in a directory, you should be using `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:]` instead. So your code should instead look like

```
NSString *images_misc_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainmenu_background" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"images/misc"];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Using `inDirectory` seems to work. But this means the behavior has (silently) changed as it works in later versions, right?

Comment: It sounds like they changed the method to handle full paths given in the `pathForResource:` parameter, but even if you're only supporting 4.0 and above it's better to use the API correctly and use the `inDirectory:` parameter for all directories.

Comment: For the record, it's a framework I'm using which does it like that. Odd that apple changed this behavior w/o any notice though.

Comment: They made it more permissive. Probably as a side-effect of reimplementing the method for some other change (e.g. supporting @2x or ~ipad modifiers).

Answer (score 10):

Even though this has been answered already, I would like to add that `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:]` has different case-sensitivity  depending whether it is iPhone simulator or iPad simulator or the device. For example, iPhone Simulator 4.0 it seems to be case insensitive, while on iPad Simulator 3.2 and the device - case sensitive. Thus files that are found on iPhone 4.0 simulator might not be found on IPad Simulator 3.2 or the device if the cases don't match.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I just got burned by the case-sensitivity difference.