# Using of subfolders does not work with pathForResource nor URLforResource

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, filesystems, directory

I read some items and was happy to find how to  [add real subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949368/nsbundle-pathforresource-is-null) 
But [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022544/nsbundle-pathforresource-returns-nil-with-subdirs) of any solutions let me see my files in subfolders. All is returning nil.

[image: Path problems with XCode]

[image: inDirectory]

I've tried pathForResource and URLforResource and inDirectory methodes.

```
        //NSString *W = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LS_ADINFO_0000_LFSB" ofType:@"xml" inDirectory:@"/2012-03-08%20(Published%20as%2008%20MAR%202012)/AERODROMES/LFSB/"];
        //urlPDF = [NSURL URLWithString:W];
        // DEBUG output: urlPDF = nil

        //urlPDF = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LFSB/LS_ADINFO_0000_LFSB.xml" withExtension:nil]; 
        // DEBUG output: urlPDF = nil


        //urlPDF = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LS_ADINFO_0000_LFSB.xml" withExtension:nil]; 
        // DEBUG output: urlPDF = file://localhost/Users/siri/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/1F5953CD-1E13-40D4-9497-8313F9DDEA77/SwissVfrm03.app/LS_ADINFO_0000_LFSB.xml
```

How to setup a subdirectory in XCode for accessing in iPad App?

Answer (score 6):

In an iOS application, nonlocalized resources are located at the top-level of the bundle directory.  You could create a custom bundle by path, but by default all resources are located at the top level of your bundle regardless of what directories you have set up in Xcode.

[iOS Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

I had a curious issue with `-pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:`.

Eventhough my resource files' directory structure was faithfully preserved in the final build (I checked this by building the app for Simulator and inspecting the app bundle's contents, in Finder), it would return a non-nil (but erroneous) path that was such as if the target file was residing at the root of the app bundle.

For example,

The file is located at:

`.../MyApp.app/Subdir1/Subdir2/file.png`

But the following code:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Subdir1/Subdir2"]
```

...gives instead:

`.../MyApp.app/file.png`

Changing all directory names to ASCII characters fixed the problem.